# How do I quit multiple versions of Firefox with Apple Script?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have two versions of firefox. One has an application name "Firefox" and the other is called "Firefox 2".

I'd like to tell AppleScript to close both instances of Firefox. Here's my code

```
tell application "Firefox" to quit
tell application "Firefox 2" to quit
```

It's weird because I can type this into Script Editor, but when I press save it always turns into this.

```
tell application "Firefox" to quit
tell application "Firefox" to quit
```

[image]

I ran this code and I'll put the output below.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theVisibleApps to (name of application processes where visible is true)
end tell

{"Finder", "Terminal", "Script Editor", "firefox", "firefox"}
```

And here's the error code: error "Firefox got an error: Connection is invalid." number -609

How do I make sure they both close?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you made a physical. on-disk copy of Firefox.app, and renamed it in the Finder to "Firefox 2.app". Is that correct? If so, that is going to cause you headaches. The visible name in the Finder isn't really used by the system much. The system uses the app's *bundle identifier* — for Firefox, I believe that's something like 'org.mozilla.firefox' — which is found in the info.plist file within the app bundle, and draws display names and such from that plist also. Unix, on the other hand, tends to use the name of the executable, which is in the MacOS folder inside the app bundle. Since your physical copy will have the same bundle ID as the original, the system will get confused if you try to distinguish between the apps that way.

The normal way to run two instances of an application is to use the unix `open` command with the `-n` option, e.g., one of these:

```
open -n '/Applications/FireFox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'

open -n -g org.mozilla.firefox
```

Each opened instance will have the same name and bundle id, but they will have different process identifiers (pid), and you can distinguish between them using those. There are a few different ways of doing that, depending on how you've set things up, but for a quick hack in AppleScript you can use something like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set unixIDs to unix id of (every process whose name is "Firefox")
end tell
```

Whichever unix ID is lower should generally be the instance that was launched first.

Comment: Just an FYI... Firefox does not allow multiple running occurrences started with the `open` _command_ to stay alive and why the OP has made second copy of the _application bundle_ and renamed it. The only thing the first example `open` _command_ does, in Terminal, is after attempting to start, it immediately terminates the additional occurrence and open another window for the other occurrence, while leaving a `[Process completed]` Terminal window open to be dealt with. The second example `open` _command_ return an error e.g. `The file /Users/me/org.mozilla.firefox does not exist.` ... Cont. ...

Comment: ... Cont. ... even though I have an occurrence of Firefox running. Using the `-b` _option_ instead of `-g` fixes the error but the end results are the same in this use case. By the way, the same holds true for Google Chrome too. That said, there is no need to worry about the **PID**'s as this can be handled differently, as shown in my answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To keep **Script Editor** from changing `"Firefox 2"` to `"Firefox"`, the real issue you're having, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* **will resolve your issue** and allow for a graceful quitting of both occurrences of **Firefox**:

```
set fx1 to "Firefox"
set fx2 to "Firefox 2"

tell application fx1 to quit
delay 2
tell application fx2 to quit
```

In the screenshot below you can see in the **Replies** *pane* that each occurrence of **Firefox** returned `error number 0`, **which is a graceful quit**! Any *error number* other then `0` means something went wrong.

[image: Script Editor window]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

If you do a 'ps' from the command line you'll get the PID for each version of Firefox. You can then kill a process by typing kill -9 PID. There should be a way to grep out the PID for each process and then kill each one.  Maybe use awk which i know little about.

Comment: You do not need to use `ps` or `awk` for that matter. One could simply use `killall firefox`, however that does not gracefully quit **Firefox**. You also do not need to first use `ps` to get the **PID** to then use `kill -9 PID` because `pkill firefox` will do just as `killall firefox` does. But if you do want to get the **PID** of **Firefox** first to use `kill` you could use `kill $(pgrep firefox)`.  That said, none of these examples will quit **Firefox** gracefully, even with the right _signal_, because **Firefox** is just very finicky/sensitive to the type of method. Believe me I've tried.

Comment: I suggested ps because the OP wanted to write a script to automate killing all versions.  Since a script was desired I suggested using ps to get PID and then use kill to kill the versions that are running.  I understand what you are saying about a graceful exit but that would require a more sophisticated script I suspect.  I don't think my answer warrants a downvote.  Certainly not 2.  My method, in theory, works as good as the others except I don't know how to pull out the PID after running ps.